# sample function gives different result in console and in knitted document when seed is set

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm creating a document in a `Rmarkdown` file and knitting to HTML for file submission. Generating seeded samples using the sample function provide different results in the console and the knitted file.

I am using R Studio version 1.0.153 and R 3.6.0

edit: I have updated R Studio to version 1.2.1335 and am still having this issue

```r
set.seed(1)
rnorm(1)
sample(1:10, 1)
```

in the console and knitted file, the value for `rnorm(1)` is the same, however, in the console, I see that I have sampled 6 in the console, and 7 in the knitted document

Comment: It generated `7` in both cases (console and knitted document) for me.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sessionInfo()` from both knitting and the Rstudio console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R 3.6.0 [changed the sampling method](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17494). With the new method (`default` or `Rejection`) I get 7. With the old one I get 6:

```r
set.seed(1)
rnorm(1)
#> [1] -0.6264538
sample(1:10, 1)
#> [1] 7

set.seed(1, sample.kind = "Rounding")
#> Warning in set.seed(1, sample.kind = "Rounding"): non-uniform 'Rounding'
#> sampler used
rnorm(1)
#> [1] -0.6264538
sample(1:10, 1)
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

So it seems you have somehow set `sample.kind = "Rounding"` in the console. You can check this from the output of `RNGkind()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly correct. `sessionInfo()` as @Russ mentioned showed non-default options (rounding) in the console, but nothing in the knit document. I was able to change it back by setting `RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rejection")`