# Samples from RcppArmadillo and R returns different outputs

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

It seems that, the `sample` functions from `RcppArmadillo` and `R` return the same outputs when I set fixed the seed for each sample. However, I get different outcomes in my case. 
Here is my code

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f(int N, NumericVector x)
{return Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(x, N, false);}


/*** R
set.seed(123)
f(5, 1:5)

[1] 2 4 5 3 1

set.seed(123)
sample(1:5, 5, FALSE)

[1] 3 2 5 4 1
*/
```

Does someone know why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sample function gives different result in console and in knitted document when seed is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56268011/sample-function-gives-different-result-in-console-and-in-knitted-document-when-s). There are probably other/more appropriate duplicates ...

Comment: Just try `set.seed(123, sample.kind = "Rounding"); sample(1:5, 5, FALSE)` in R. The `RcppArmadillo::sample` (and `Rcpp::sample`) functions still use the older "Rounding" algorithm.

Comment: See also https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/250 and https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/945.